# Can someone help edit Javascript string with both a for loop and the splice command?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm writing a script that's going to take some information about the website that you visit. I have copied this small portion of my code that I'm struggling with. This part of the code is supposed check if the visited website is using the www prefix and remove that prefix, then there is another part of the code that I haven't pasted stores the domain name in the variable website.

```
var website = location.hostname;
document.getElementById("displayBefore").innerHTML = website; //test to see the variable
if (website[0] == 'w' && website[1] == 'w' && website[2] == 'w' && website[3] == '.') {
    document.getElementById("displayTrue1").innerHTML = "true"; //test to see if the conditional was met
    for (i = 4; i < website.length; i++) {
        website[i - 4] = website[i]; //this is not rewriting anything
        document.getElementById("displayPos0").innerHTML = website[i]; //test to see if the for loop has run
    }
    document.getElementById("displayDuring").innerHTML = website; //test to see the variable
    website.splice(0, 4); //this is breaking everything after it
    document.getElementById("displayAfter").innerHTML = website; //test to see the variable
}
```

Here is what's actually being displayed when in those tests when I pull it up in a browser:

```
WebsiteBeforeFix: www.example.com
True1: true
website[i]: m
WebsiteDuringFix: www.example.com
WebsiteAfterFix:
```

The two parts of the code that aren't working are the following:

```
website[i - 4] = website[i];
```

This is supposed to pretty much shift the letters over 4 spaces to the left(eliminating "www.").

```
website.splice(0,4);
```

This is actually causing nothing after it to display at all in any of the code that does work. Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` is an array method, not for strings (they're immutable). Make the variable an array to manipulate it using the `split` method, and join it back together using the `join` method:

```
var websiteStr = location.hostname;
var website = websiteStr.split('');
console.log("displayBefore: " + website.join(''));
if (websiteStr.indexOf("www.") === 0) {
    console.log("true");
    /*for (var i = 4; i < website.length; i++) {
        website[i - 4] = website[i];
        console.log("displayPos0: " + website[i]);
    }*/
    console.log("displayDuring: " + website.join(''));
    website.splice(0, 4);
    console.log("displayAfter: " + website.join(''));
}
```

Instead of manipulating HTML, you can use `console.log` to do basic logging at particular points, which will show up in your browser's console. Anyway, it seems that your for loop doesn't do what you want it to -- `splice` already removes the "www." prefix.

You can also change this:

```
if (website[0] == 'w' && website[1] == 'w' && website[2] == 'w' && website[3] == '.') {
```

to this:

```
if (websiteStr.indexOf("www.") === 0) {
```

which performs the same thing much more concisely.

With the fixed code, it now displays:

```
displayBefore: www.google.com
true
displayDuring: www.google.com
displayAfter: google.com
```

Comment: Amazing, that one command solves everything. I don't know why I thought splice was for strings. And thanks for the other basic tips.

Comment: @AaronT: also what's the for loop meant to do? Seems that it's not quite right.

Comment: Just read your comment. The loop was meant to shift the characters in the string but now it's not needed.

Comment: @AaronT: which wouldn't have done anything, since strings are immutable. And you're welcome. When you can, take a look at the [About] page.